# unable to uninstall Postgres completely from ubuntu

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I installed Postgres by following this link but now not able to completely remove it.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/linux-postgresql-install-and-configure-from-source/

On running:**Sudo apt-get --purge remove postgres**   or **Sudo apt-get --purge remove psql** getting this response

Package 'postgresql' is not installed, so not removed

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libappindicator1 libindicator7 python-appindicator
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 281 not upgraded.

Which psql

/usr/local/pgsql

which postgres

*didn't show anything here*

I am able to run Postgres using

su postgres

/usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand that the binaries (and other files) *from packages* end up below `/usr` (and maybe `/var/` etc) whereas the binaries *you or someone else* installed locally go to `/usr/local`.

So if `which psql` reveals `/usr/local/pgsql` you may have to remove that by hand, and not via `apt-get`.

Also, `postgres` is a *user* not a binary / program you run.